# Handling deeply nested data in React components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm facing a dilemma in my components where the data I am trying to access doesn't "exist" yet. For example, when I log my redux actions I get the following:
[image]
[image]

The first image is what my data looks like while it's loading, the second picture is what my nested data looks like received.

Because of this, I'm having to run checks inside of the render method of my components such as:

```
const data = homepage.upcomingTrips.data.upcoming_hikes;
{ !loading && data && data.upcoming_hikes &&
    ...more code here
}
```

_reducers/homepage/upcoming_trips.reducer.js:

```
import { homepageConstants } from '../../_constants';

export function upcomingTrips(state = {}, action) {

switch (action.type) {
    case homepageConstants.UPCOMING_TRIPS_REQUEST:
        return {
            data: {},
            loading: true,
        };
    case homepageConstants.UPCOMING_TRIPS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            data: action.data,
            loading: false,
        };
    case homepageConstants.UPCOMING_TRIPS_FAILURE:
        return {
            error: action.error,
        };

    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

_reducers/homepage/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { currentPack } from './current_pack.reducer';
import { totalMiles } from './total_miles.reducer';
import { upcomingTrips } from './upcoming_trips.reducer';

const homepage = combineReducers({
    currentPack,
    totalMiles,
    upcomingTrips,
});

export default homepage;
```

_reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { authentication } from './authentication.reducer';
import { registration } from './registration.reducer';
import { users } from './users.reducer';
// import { homepageData } from './homepage.reducer';
import homepage from './homepage';
import { explorepageData } from './explorepage.reducer';
import { alert } from './alert.reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authentication,
  registration,
  users,
  homepage,
  explorepageData,
  alert
});

export default rootReducer;
```

UpcomingTrips.jsx:

```
class UpcomingTrips extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUpcomingTrips();
    }

    render() {
        const { classes, homepage } = this.props;
        const data = homepage.upcomingTrips.data.upcoming_hikes;
        const loading = homepage.upcomingTrips.data.loading;
        console.log('homepage: ', homepage.upcomingTrips.data.upcoming_hikes);

        return (
            <UpcomingTripStyles>
                <Typography variant='h4' className={ `${ classes.headline } ${ classes.widgetName }` }>
                    Upcoming Trips
                </Typography>
                { loading && <img src='/static/loading.svg' alt='loading' className='loading-img' /> }
                <ul className='upcoming-hikes'>
                    { !loading && data && data.upcoming_hikes &&
                        data.upcoming_hikes.map((h) =>
                            <li className='hike-item' key={ h.id }>
                            <span className='start-date'>{ toDate(h.start_date) }</span>
                            <span className='hike-name'>{ h.name }</span>
                            </li>,
                        )
                    }
                    { !loading && data && !_.toArray(data.upcoming_hikes).length &&
                        <p>You haven't created any Upcoming Hikes yet!</p>
                    }
                </ul>
            </UpcomingTripStyles>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { homepage } = state;
    return {
        homepage,
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getUpcomingTrips: () => {
            dispatch(homepageActions.getUpcomingTrips())
        }
    };
};

const enhance = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    withStyles(styles),
);

const connectedUpcomingTrips = enhance(UpcomingTrips);
export { connectedUpcomingTrips as UpcomingTrips };
```

So what's the best way to handle all of this? Should I look into flattening my data with something like Normalizr? Or does it have more to do with the way my reducers are working?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You seem to be handling the loading case just fine in your code

Comment: Ah apologies. When the page attempts to render, I get an error telling me "TypeError: homepage.upcomingTrips.data is undefined".

Comment: You know that key won't exist immediately - you need to check if it's available.

Comment: Is it normal for a component to have to have checks for data nested that deeply though? Perhaps "normal" isn't even the best term here, but maybe "ideal"?

Comment: There's nothing abnormal about it. A "cleaner" solution (which is completely subject to opinion) is to have a parent component (often an HOC) load the data and show a loading spinner and then render the actual component once the data is ready. That way you separate the data and the view, having a "smart" component (the data loader) and a "dumb" component (the view).

Comment: Yep makes total sense. Thank you for the conversation, this has been totally helpful.